# few signals handling in c

Tags: c, signals, ipc

I want to handle 2 different signals (`SIGWINCH`, `SIGALRM`) during program lifecycle. Let, for instance, `SIGWINCH` signal build a frame around terminal edge, whenever it called. And `SIGALRM` print current time inside of this frame.

How is it possible to handle both signals at the same time. I guess, it should be `pause` somewhere.

Here is my code ideas for that.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   print_frame();
   struct sigaction sa_winch;
   struct sigaction sa_alarm;
   sa_winch.sa_handler = winch_handler;
   sa_alarm.sa_handler = alarm_handler; 
   alarm(1);
   while(1) {
     if (sigaction(SIGWINCH,&sa_winch, NULL) == -1) {
       perror("SIGWINCH");
     }
     if (sigaction(SIGALRM,&sa_alarm, NULL) == -1 ) {
       perror("SIGALRM");
     }

   }
  return 0;
}

void winch_handler (int signum) {
   print_frame();
}


void alarm_handler(int signum) {
  print_time();
  alarm(1);
}
```

Comment: With the right initialization of the `sigaction` structures, you should only call `sigaction` *once*. Or only *after* a signal have been triggered. I suggest you find yourself a book, tutorial, or just read the plain manual pages.

Comment: Note also that you can safely call async-signal-safe functions **only** from within a signal handler.  Calls such as `printf()` are **not** async-signal-safe.